# Updateable query error message in MS Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would be grateful for some help, please, in understanding why the below query returns the "Operation must use an updateable query" message:

```
UPDATE QC_Costs
SET    QC_Costs.No_Makes = (SELECT Count(Temp_Tbl.Unique_ID) AS MakesCount
                            FROM   (SELECT GSR.Unique_ID,
                                           GSR.Month_Name,
                                           GSR.Year_No
                                    FROM   GSR
                                           INNER JOIN Products
                                                   ON Products.Unique_ID = GSR.Product_ID
                                    WHERE  ( ( ( Products.Item_category ) = "MAKE" )
                                             AND ( ( GSR.Transaction_Type ) = "Invoice" ) )) AS Temp_Tbl
                            WHERE  ( ( ( Temp_Tbl.Month_Name ) = QC_Costs.Month_Name )
                                     AND ( ( Temp_Tbl.Year_No ) = QC_Costs.Year_No ) ));
```

I have read numerous articles that this message appears when permissions to update the database are not set correctly. I have tried to make those changes to the folder permissions (although everything already looked fine), and what I don't fully understand is if I write a different query where I simply want to make the No_Makes field in the QC_Costs table a 1, the query runs fine. This leads me to believe the issue is in my count query or sub-query, but when I turn this section of the query into a SELECT query and run it on its own it returns a result.

I am not an expert at all - I have only tried to work with sub-queries today for the first time - so I would really appreciate some help.

For context - I have a table full of invoices and credit notes (the GSR). Another table called Products contains a list of products that has an Item_Category field. The GSR is linked to Products via a Product_ID field. A third table called QC_Costs has a record for each month and a field called No_Makes. I want to capture the number of invoices for MAKE products for a given month in the GSR and update the No_Makes field in the QC_Costs table with that number. This number will be used in another query I am yet to write or may add to this one where an amount of costs is divided by No_Makes and then this value is posted back into the GSR against each of these records.

I hope the above makes sense - please let me know if I need to provide anything further.

Thank you

EDIT:

In response to Parfait's answers I have written the following and it runs - thank you:

```
UPDATE QC_Costs 
SET QC_Costs.QC_Cost_Allocation = 
DLookup("SumOfQC_Costs_To_Allocate", "Sum_Of_QC_Costs","Month_Name = " & [QC_Costs].[Month_Name] & " AND Year_No = " & [QC_Costs].[Year_No]) / 
DLookUp("CountofUniqueID","Count_Of_Makes","Month_Name = " & [QC_Costs].[Month_Name] & " AND Year_No = " & [QC_Costs].[Year_No]);
```

I am really close but I get a message for every record where this will execute that there is a type conversion failure. The data type of the destination field is Double, and I have made sure the denominator Dlookup query isn't a zero so the answer to this division should be a numeric decimal, so can anyone explain to me how to troubleshoot what's wrong, please?

I'm now off the question topic so I apologise for that - please let me know if I have to repost as a new question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access update queries must not be [read-only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) in order to be run. It does not have to do with proper permissions. Aggregate queries are not updateable which you are attempting to assign to *No_Makes* with `COUNT()`.

Consider `DLookup` function which externally retrieves your value from a saved query:

**Select** Query *(save as stored query object)*

```
SELECT Count(GSR.Unique_ID) AS CountUniqueID,
       GSR.Month_Name,
       GSR.Year_No
FROM   GSR
INNER JOIN Products
     ON Products.Unique_ID = GSR.Product_ID
WHERE (((Products.Item_category) = 'MAKE')
  AND  ((GSR.Transaction_Type) = 'Invoice'))
GROUP BY GSR.Month_Name,
         GSR.Year_No
```

**Update** Query

```
UPDATE QC_Costs
SET    QC_Costs.No_Makes = DLookup("CountUniqueID", "mySavedQuery", 
                                   "Month_Name='" & QC_Costs.Month_Name & "' 
                                    AND Year_No = " & QC_Costs.Year_No)
```

*Aside - it's often said that one should not save computations or calculations in database tables as they can easily be retrieved from queries for reporting. Instead, use table storage for raw values.*

Comment: Thank you so much. I’ll study this and see if I can get it to work.

On your final point - sorry but would you explain what you mean please? What’s table storage as opposed to what I’m doing here?

Comment: Understood. For final point, you are using table resources to save calculations which can be achieved via queries of the tables. This is a bit redundant. When you need such calculations simply query the tables.

Comment: If I was to say that initially I wanted to nest this query within the main query that allocated the costs would that be doing what you mean? I broke it down only because it was getting a bit too complicated for me, but I agree saving the number somewhere isn’t great. I agree - getting that count on the fly is what I really wanted to do. Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: I know what you are attempting to do. It's no the *how* but the *why* question, `COUNT()` from group by aggregate queries are inexpensive to run. But again, this is just a best practice note. Let me know if soluion worked as needed.

Comment: Ok will do. I’m out now so haven’t looked at this properly yet but one last thing has come to mind - how do you create stored query objects in Access? Will I have to do this through VBA or is it something on the menu bar? Thanks again.

Comment: Just save the `SELECT` statement in Create / Query Design (SQL view) assuming you have MSAccess.exe.

Comment: Hi again - I've done what you said and it works. However, in taking things through to what I was ultimately trying to do I've hit another snag which I've detailed in an edit in my main question.

Comment: Convert your `UPDATE` query to a `SELECT` statement with same exact `DLookUp` and check those types and values.

Comment: OK so I've done it!! The issue was a total schoolboy error - I didn't have single quote marks around my string argument for Month_Name, so I suspect the two DLookups were evaluating to zero, therefore dividing 0 by 0. That will have been evaluating to some sort of error, and naturally that won't be a double. I do, however, have performance issues running this query on the GSR (where 7,034 rows meet my criteria). I am going to store the allocation once (given the result for each invoice is the same £3.41) and then run another much simpler query to copy that value against all 7,034 invoices.